# LINQ to SQL - converting temporary users to real users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, model-view-controller

In creating a new ASP.NET MVC application, I have an issue with the approach I'm using to store user-created data for temporary users who have yet to create an account which I then try to convert to a real user. That probably doesn't make much sense, so let me explain:

- A visitor to the site can enter profile settings before being made to register with a username, password, etc.
- I'm creating database entries via LINQ to SQL for a new user in this case, using the Request.AnonymousID value as a temporary username.
- When the user chooses to register, I need to 'switch over' the relevant database records to use the newly entered username instead of the temporary one.

The problem is that when I try to update the record I can't because the username is the primary key, so I'm forced to delete the record and add a new one...

I can probably persevere with this, but I think I might just be going about this in completely the wrong way and wondered if anyone could suggest a better way to allow visitors to store information before they've registered and have that carry over when they do.

I know about profiles but want the profile information to be available to other visitors. I also know that I can create an anonymous profile but it seems like I should be able to keep the data model out of the web.config file.

Comment: I'm quite surprised you can't update the primary key, as long as it doesn't collide with anything else in the table - what error/exception are you seeing?

Comment: Maybe that's not it, then. I don't have the error in front of me right now, but I know that when I tried to delete+add instead I got a "cannot attach to entity that already exists" error.

I have a field which is an identity and so it might be that I have an issue generating a new value for that field. I also have a FK relationship between the username in the two tables I'm trying to modify.

Comment: So...um...yeah. Maybe the foreign key is the problem and I should just remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having an independent primary key for the table with your custom user data.
And then have fields like `RefAnonymousId` and `RefUserId` to relate that user data to the anonymous user and the registered user, respectively.

For example:

```
TABLE UserData
(
    UserDataID  int  IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY,
    RefAnonymousId  uniqueidentifier,
    RefUserId  uniqueidentifier,
    ... (data fields),
    (maybe also unique keys on RefUserId and RefAnonymousId)
)
```

That way you will also be able to identify the user when the user is logged out and maybe automatically log the user in...

Comment: Oh, I like that. I'll try it and get back to you.